# Self-document a type-alias (typedef) to indicate that it will be used in another certain class

Tags: c++, templates, documentation, c++14, typedef

How to self-document a type-alias that is used in another certain library?

In the below example, class `User` defines an alias `User::type` that is supposed to be referred only in class `Library` via `T::type`.

Here is the diagram :-

[image]

### **Library.h**

`Library<T>` expected only `T` that defines a certain alias (e.g. `T::type` in this example).

```
#include <iostream>
class Base{};     //dummy for the sake of example
template<class T>class Library{
    Base* t=nullptr;
    public: typename T::type getValue(){return static_cast<typename T::type>(t);}
    //some complex function, e.g. T::aType::doSomething()
};
```

In real cases, `Library<T>` expected **many** alias e.g. `T::aType`, `T::bType`, `T::callbackType`, etc.

### **User.h**

To use the above library, `::type` has to be defined e.g. as below :-

```
class Derived : public Base{};  //dummy for the sake of example
class User{
    public: using type=Derived*;//<-- poorly documented
    //... other alias e.g. aType=int*, bType=SomeClass*
    //... other complex functions
};
```

Here is the usage (**[full demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e446452eab4c8461)**):-

```
int main(){
     Library<User> lib;
     lib.getValue();
     std::cout<<"OK"<<std::endl;
}
```

### Problem

Notice that `User::type` really lacks self-documentation.
In real life, most coders - including ones who designed it - forget what `User::type` is for.

`User::type` is not referred internally in `User.h`, so it is an easy target to be randomly deleted by some coders.

I feel that our beloved codes are rotten from inside, and I think about ways to save it.

## Question

How to self document the type alias to indicate how/where it is *called*?

## My poor solutions

### 1. comment

```
 class User{
    /** It is used for Library.h */
    public: using type=Derived*;
```

It gets dirty pretty fast, and I still prefer using C++-semantic rather than random comment.

### 2. make the type name more descriptive

```
 class User{
    /** It is used for Library.h */
    public: using LIBRARY_type=Derived*;
```

It is quite messy.

**Note:** This question is similar to [How to self-document a callback function that is called by template library class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43445184), but this one is about `type-def` while that one is about `callback`.

Comment: You could use a *type traits* class. Arguably, its more work. But you could keep all the documentation in the traits class. So, you always access the typedef through the trait class. Like `std::iterator_traits`. Though this is not scalable for multiple behaviors

Comment: @WhiZTiM [It](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) sounds like a good idea.  Thank.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your only actual problem here is that "it is an easy target to be randomly deleted by some coders".

The solution to this is not to obsess over self-documentation and names, but to institute *peer review* and *regression tests*. Why are coders on your team "randomly deleting" things and getting away with it? That needs to stop.

You can probably save the administrative headache of having to rollback such a change, with a simple code comment:

```
/**
 * Provided for use by Library.
 */
using type=Derived*;
```

That's it. That's all you need. It's not "dirty" in the slightest — it tells other coders why the `type` declaration exists, and will stand out like a sore thumb in `diff`s if anyone removes it. Then you can ask them, "how did you conclude that Library no longer requires this declaration, and why is removing it worth the breakage of our API?"

In short, this is only a human problem. There are plenty of examples in the standard library of member types called `type`, so from a technical standpoint you're already doing what you should. Don't try to shoe-horn in names that reflect your type's expected *usage*; make the name describe what it *is*. The C++ committee made the same mistake with `std::move`!

Comment: I am curious, what is the mistake with `std::move`?

Answer (score 1):

You may create a type traits for that:

```
template <typename T> struct library_trait; // No definition
// Need to define library_trait<T>::type for ...
// library_trait<T>::atype for ...
```

In class `Library`, use `library_trait<T>::type` instead of `typename T::Type`

In a place before the usage of `Library<User>` (as in `main` in your example):

Specialize `library_trait` for `User`.

```
template <> struct library_trait<User>
{
    using type = Derived*;
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A trait class is the usual solution to this problem.  It is awkward because you have to specialize it within its own namespace.

An alternative is to create a trait function.

```
namespace utility {
  template<class T>struct tag_t{using type=T; constexpr tag_t(){}};
  template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
  template<class Tag> using type_t=typename Tag::type;
}
namespace MyLibrary {
  template<class T>
  void library_trait_name_f(tag_t<T>,...);
  template<class T>using library_trait_name=type_t<decltype(library_trait_name_f(tag<T>))>;
}
```

now suppoae you have:

```
namespace Elsewhere {
  struct Foo;
}
```

you can write anywhere:

```
namespace Elsewhere { // or MyLibrary, or even utility
  tag_t<int> library_trait_name_f(tag_t<Foo>);
}
```

and if visible it will be picked up by `MyLibrary::library_trait_name<T>`.  In particular, `MyLibrary::library_trait_name<Elsewhere::Foo>` is `int`.

The advantage of this is that it permits you to write thr binding between the library and the type in the library, next to the type, or in a 3rd location.  The big disadvantages is the lack of scoping and the unconventionality of it.

MSVC also doesn't behave well with decltype based SFINAE, so using the above for SFINAE in MSVC you need be careful.

Comment: The "clue" word in another your answer (about function) is within `tag<xxx>`, but the "clue" word in this answer (about typedef) is `library_trait_name_f`, correct?